# How to append markers to google maps using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

SO i'm creating a godview for my app so i can see the current users in realtime but i'm stuck with this problem. i render my map on loading using ajax and this displays the first user in my table as a marker on the map.

```
function getUsers(){

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { 
    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); 
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xmlhttp.statusText === "OK"){

        var China = {lat: 9.081999, lng: -8.675277};
        var image = "node.png";

        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
              zoom: 3,
              center: China,
              draggable: true,
              streetViewControl: true,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

            lastid = data[i].lastid;


            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude),
                map: map,
                icon: image
            });
        }
    }
}
```

when the app loads the first time, i get just the first user which is fine. Then subsequently, i want to fetch the new user where the id is greater than the first last one at a certain interval.

```
//Php that fetches the new result
    $lastId = $_GET['lastid'];

    $sql = "select * from user where id > '$lastId' limit 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($result){

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count > 0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $user = ['lastid' => $row['id'], 'username' => $row['username'], 'latitude' => $row['latitude'], 'longitude' => $row['longitude']];
            }

            echo json_encode($user);
        }
    }


//Ajax call fetches the new users look something like this
function addNewUser(lastid){


if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { 
    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); 
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xmlhttp.statusText === "OK"){

        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        lastid = data.lastid;

    }
}

xmlhttp.open('GET', 'fetchusers.php?user&lastid=' + lastid,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

i try to pass the lastid, and run some interval method in my onload to get the latest. My dilemma is appending this new result as markers to the map so that its appended without a refresh and updates automatically, item by item.

```
window.onload = function(){
  getUsers();

  setInterval(() => {
    addNewUser(lastid);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make a new map for each user, create one global map variable, initialize it once, then add your users to it.

Comment: Grt, thats one way to go bout it. But your answer doesn't do justice to appending the markers using ajax

Comment: What issue are you having doing that? If you want working code, provide a [mcve]